# What are some horrific experiments I can conduct on human subjects?

Tags: biology, science-in-society

I've joined a secret organization where I can conduct any weird and twisted experiments I please without the restrictions of so called "Ethical Standards" or "Human Rights." But I'm having a bit of researchers block.

What are some horrible experiments I can conduct on human subjects that I might not be able to due to ethical and/or legal restrictions? Bonus points for ideas that are horrific, something to human biology rather than psychological (although I am open to those), or preferably both. These can also include things to do with human fetuses.

Edit: I'm going to make these answers more directed by asking for possible experiments that could lead to extending or maximizing human life. Maybe that involves stealing someone's blood, maybe that involves human cloning to harvest organs, whatever. As long as its with the general direction of extending life as long as possible.

Comment: This is pretty close to being too broad, it may be worth tightening scope a little. That said it's perfectly answerable like this so up to you

Comment: Josef Mengele is your friend.

Comment: I don't see this as Worldbuilding at all.  It's just a rather revolting request for a list of awful things to do to people.

Comment: @StephenG it may be gross but the question is asking for some ideas to help build the world

Comment: Oh just got one more ides, make some humans be able to do photosynthesis then they will be come diabetic from all the sugar they produce

Comment: @Pingcode I decided you're probably right based on the answers so far so I've added an edit.

Comment: @user45751 haha I like that one

Comment: In this edit, do you mean extending one *particular* person in your world or extending people's lives generally or extending the lives of people in a particular group ?

Comment: @StephenG In this context for one particular guy but I don't see why the medical principles and precedures developed wouldn't be able to apply to anyone.

Comment: It's a question of numbers.  Strange as it may seem, extreme cruelty that is *institutionalized* and made into a *mass process* becomes sort of normal for a society or part of it.  Cruelty that is directed infrequently at one person or a very small group of people each time can become "personal" for those doing it.  Also secret organizations doing things on a large scale like this would inevitably attract a lot of attention.  So the numbers matter as does the objective.  Widespread use of the "results" would risk greater exposure for the group.

Comment: @StephenG Okay yeah. The research is not meant to be spread to the public its only for use within the organization.

Answer (score 8):

You don't have to do too much research to find that most of the horrific ideas people could devise [have already been done](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nazi_human_experimentation) during WWII.

Nazi experiments were responsible for much of our early knowledge about how hypothermia affected people, not to mention live testing of everything from bomb detonations to mustard gas exposure. Then there were the experimental immunisation therapies, transplantation experiments; the list goes on and I'm not prepared to type it out anymore.

Ironically, many of the results of this experimentation led to advances that could save lives. Many scientists however refused to use the data gathered this way because of the ethical issues. It's true that if you're prepared to bypass the ethical considerations you can advance science more rapidly, and find out things about the human body that could short cut normal advances by a generation or more in time. BUT; is it worth it?

Personally? I say keep your secret organisation. All the scientific curiosity in the world couldn't make me do such things to other people and I feel obliged to point out that many of the formalised processes to protect scientific ethical integrity were born from the events during WWII, and serve the scientific community far more than they restrict it.

Whatever your affiliation, don't be trying any of this at home.

Comment: +1 for 'it's already been done.'   Nazi experiments have the advantage of having been done by a group of people we are comfortable with demonizing.  People look at you a little weird if you go around all day thinking of really unethical experiments to do, but if you just look up what Nazi's did it's simply research.  Also, if you need something unethical beyond what the Nazi's did, you may find it difficult to find people who are willing to admit they thought of worse things =)

Answer (score 2):

Broadly, the simplest and quickest way to answer 'What happens if X happens to a human?' Is to simply *do* X to a human.

Does my new treatment for radiation poisoning work?

Real world:
Let's figure out a way to model this on a cell culture, then test it on animals and make sure it's safe, then finally the next time there's an accident we'll try it.

Psycho world:
I dunno, let's throw a prisoner into the reactor and find out!

Your secret society probably falls into category B. Any experiment to find out what happens with a human in X conditions will fit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

A huge amount of the answer depends on your motives and aims.

Did you join to further some specific research, or because of your interest/work in some specific field? Then you'll probably know exactly what experiments you want to do and can't normally. The answer will be dictated by what you want to learn, that you feel hindered from discovering under normal rules.

Are you simply a sadist, or want to feel powerful? (Or perhaps amoral/sociopathically curious?). Then you'll probably have no research goal, just an interest in hideous experiments. Perhaps you'll figure a goal on the way.

Are you weak and easily led? Then you'll probably end up going along with others, who will be in one of these above groups.

If none of these - why did you join?

Answer (score 1):

Oh, horrific experiments, now that’s my specialty. Their are some pretty horrific things you can do in the psychological realm but if you want biological and psychological you could use biological warfare tests on humans. Their is one weapon that was planned to be used you could test on humans(though more psychological than biological) and it’s called the gay bomb(it’s an actual thing). Next up you could do parasitic wasp, worms, bot flies,or fungus tests on humans deforming them with the spore holding things that come out or babies which feed on the humans insides until they are a shell. And you could genetically modify the bot fly eggs to corrode or explode the skin when hatching. Or make some freaky new disease which deforms and kills slowly like a modified super Ebola aids. You could do animal, human hybridization which you take zygotes(pre-fetuses) and use a little tool called crisper to splice animal DNA and slowly learning how to implement it into human while leaving many humans deformed, dead, and crippled for life in the process. If you want the grossest hybridizations possible go with invertebrates their life cycles are so different to ours it would look gross happening to a human(see in the movie “The Fly”). Oh and naked mole rats would be another great choice, not only are they hideous and could leave a person deformed, their is a justifiable reason to hybridize with it, it’s the only mammal immune to cancer. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

cutting out parts of brains to see what stops working when you do. accidental brain injuries have taught us a lot about how brains work, you just do the same thing systematically.